# Как переключаться между вкладками в браузере с помощью скрипта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, расширения, tabs, плагин

Работаю с расширением (плагином) для браузера, и нужно сделать скрипт, который будет переключать на любую, нужную мне вкладку в браузере, например на пятую вкладку.

Нужно сделать что-то вроде этого:

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({status: "complete"}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.focus(tabs[4].id); // - есть ли что-то подобное?
});
```